# Application Error, While deploying heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the result of `heroku logs`. I don't know what is this log trying to say. Please help. Stuck more than a weeks.

```
2014-02-18T11:57:30.430725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=cams.herokuapp.com request_id=fd7de01f-4602-4463-8100-070bf07957fa fwd="110.44.114.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5949ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-02-18T11:57:30.918774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cams.herokuapp.com request_id=8841b213-7b02-466e-ac8d-94ca8d3a6f3c fwd="110.44.114.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228
```

What does that error meant to be... ???? 
While it works perfectly in localhost. Dont know what is missing in heroku. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `actionpack-action_caching` in your Gemfile? The action caching methods have been removed in 4.0.

Comment: I did installed but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above are quite useful, but the problem was just with the css file (some syntax error). So if any one facing such problem should make sure if there exist no syntax errors and other errors even though the app is running in localhost. 
Thank you guys for your great help!!!

This may not be a probable right answer but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a error that you logs file generated

```
class:SitemapsController>': undefined method `caches_page' for Spud::SitemapsController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Its a gem and it works fine in localhost, the only problem is with heroku. I think the problem is with route, but not sure about that.

Comment: may be that gem not deploy your app on heroku.

Comment: Try to run rails in production mode `rails s -e production`

Comment: It gave such error :::::: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)

Comment: what does that mean. I have sqlite3 in gemfile too

Comment: I think in production you are using 'postgresql' database. You may not be that database/adapter in local. Try by adding `include ActionController::Caching` into your sitemapcontroller

Comment: error log was as mentioned in the updated question. What does it means.

Comment: See my answer and Try that

Answer (score 0):

Add these configeration to your `SitemapController`

```
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::Caching
  include AbstractController::Layouts

  self.page_cache_directory = Rails.public_path
  self.perform_caching = true
  self.cache_store = ActionController::Base.cache_store
```

Comment: What is SitemapController. It may be embarrasing but I really dont know about tha..

Comment: May be SitemapController is using some gems. Then add this to ApplicationController

Comment: Didn't Work!!! [Error] 
2014-02-18T12:24:53.692183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico 
.......

Comment: Run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: I did solved this problem. The problem was with my css file (some syntax error). But wondering why the same file was working with localhost. Thank you anyway!!!!